# Unable to load large amount of data when running the SQL Loader Process through Java

Tags: java, sql-loader, controlfile

My Sample CSV File that I need to upload to DB has a little over 10000 records.
I am executing sql loader command through Java method call:

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(sqlLdrCmd);
```

this uploads 4924 records and then the execution just hangs waiting for CSV to upload.

just wanted to highlight that this is just a sample CSV that I am using, my actual csv would contain close to a million records.

My ctl File looks something like this:

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=1)
LOAD
  DATA 
  INFILE 'samples.csv'

  BADFILE 'samples.bad'
  DISCARDFILE 'samples.dsc'
  APPEND INTO TABLE TAB_SAMPLE
    EVALUATE CHECK_CONSTRAINTS
    REENABLE DISABLED_CONSTRAINTS
    EXCEPTIONS EXCEPTION_TABLE
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," 
  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  TRAILING NULLCOLS
  ( 
    SOURCE_NAME,
ASSOC1_NAME,
ASSOC2_NAME,
ASSOC3_NAME,
ENTITY_NAME,
ATTRIBUTE_GROUP,
ATTRIBUTE_NAME,
TYPE,
STRING_VALUE,
INTEGER_VALUE,
LONG_VALUE,
FLOAT_VALUE,
DOUBLE_VALUE,
BOOLEAN_VALUE,
TIMESTAMP_VALUE,
TIME_POINT_VALUE
)
```

The command runs just fine and uploads entire data when I execute from prompt directly.

There is no Foreign key constraint on this table

please suggest way out, let me know if anything is unclear

Comment: Why through Java? You can run this directly via the `mysql` command line. No need to involve Java in it at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should split the process. I don't know which database are you using but SQL server has an 8k limit.

Comment: I can see that you are attempting to be helpful, but your answer is making assumptions that are not warranted.  In addition, we expect people to use proper capitalization and punctuation ... and proper english words.  (The letter "u" is not an English word ... except in an SMS or Tweet.)  Finally, your suggested solution ("split the process") needs to be explained in more detail.